# Checking if a multiplication table represents a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Given an $n \times n$ multiplication table,
can one check if it represents a group in $o(n^3)$ time?
All properties can be checked by mindless try-all possibilities loops:

- Whether there is an identity element can be checked in $O(n^2)$ time.
- Whether every element has an inverse can be checked in $O(n^2)$ time.
- And associativity can be checked in $O(n^3)$ time.

My question is:

> **Q**. Is there a faster algorithm for arbitrary tables, a subcubic algorithm?

This hardly needs illustration, but here is a multiplication table
that would be $D_4$ if the two highlighted entries
were swapped:

---

[image: GroupXTable8]

---

There is an identity element $1$, and every element has an inverse, but
associativity fails:
$$2 \cdot (5 \cdot 3) \neq (2 \cdot 5) \cdot 3$$
$$2 \cdot 4 \neq 6 \cdot 3$$
$$3 \neq 8$$
So this table does not represent a group.